# Object is possibly "null" in event.target.files in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to upload a csv file and later parse it in json format, I have created a state in which i am setting the file using the HTMLEvent Property.I am using typescript I have defined the possible types while defining the state but I am still getting the error.

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  IconButton,
  Modal,
  Stack,
  LinearProgress,
  Typography
} from '@mui/material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import UploadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Upload';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Cancel';
import { csvFileParser } from '../../../utils/csvFileParser';

type Props = {};

const BulkServiceUpload = (props: Props) => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [filename, setFileName] = useState<File | undefined | null>();
  console.log(filename);

  const style = {
    position: 'absolute' as 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 600,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    borderRadius: '1rem',
    borderWidth: 0,
    p: 4
  };

  const serviceMasterParser = async () => {
    if (filename === null) {
      alert('Please select a file');
    } else {
      const parsedCSVData: object[] = csvFileParser(filename);
      console.log(parsedCSVData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="success"
          onClick={() => setOpenModal(true)}
        >
          <UploadIcon />
          Add Service
        </Button>
      </Box>

      <Modal open={openModal} onClose={() => setOpenModal(false)}>
        <Stack padding={3} sx={style} spacing={3}>
          <Typography marginY={3} variant="h5" fontWeight={600}>
            Upload Service in Bulk
          </Typography>
          <Box
            sx={{
              border: 'dashed 1px black',
              borderRadius: '1rem',
              position: 'relative',

              background: '#f0f0f0',
              '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: '#EFFAF5'
              }
            }}
          >
            <Box position="absolute" width="100%" height="100%" p={3}>
              <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <UploadIcon />
                <Typography>Bulk Upload Service Master</Typography>
              </Box>

              <Typography fontSize="10px" textAlign="center">
                only .csv file is supported
              </Typography>
            </Box>

            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".csv"
              onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                setFileName((e.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0]!)
              }
              style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '150px',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                opacity: '0'
              }}
            />

            <Box
              p={1}
              display={`${filename === null ? 'none' : 'flex'}`}
              justifyContent="space-between"
              alignItems="center"
              sx={{
                background: '#f5f5f5',
                borderRadius: '15px'
              }}
              margin={2}
            >
              <Typography fontSize={14}>{filename?.name!}</Typography>
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="delete file"
                component="label"
                onClick={() => {
                  setFileName(undefined);
                }}
              >
                <CancelIcon fontSize="small" />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
            {/* <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={50} /> */}
          </Box>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="success"
            onClick={() => serviceMasterParser()}
          >
            <UploadIcon />
            Bulk Upload
          </Button>
          <Button color="success" fullWidth variant="contained">
            Add Single Service
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default BulkServiceUpload;
```

I don't want any initial value for my file.But If i will take useState value empty it will be by default an undefined value. Which is creating this problem. Please let me know how can I solve this .This is my first question so if I have made any mistake my appologies in advance.

Comment: There is a lot of code there. Please read on how to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Make sure files exists in the target

```
 onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
     setFileName((e.target as HTMLInputElement)?.files?.[0])
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everyone I think I have made a small typo error while setting the value of a file

```
 <input
          type="file"
          accept=".csv"
          onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
            setFileName((e.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0]!)
          }
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '150px',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            opacity: '0'
          }}
        />
```

I should have used the ! after files and it resolved the issue

```
 <input
          type="file"
          accept=".csv"
          onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
            setFileName((e.target as HTMLInputElement).files![0])
          }
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '150px',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            opacity: '0'
          }}
        />
```

Comment: This isn't safe. If it is null/undefined, your application will crash. You should checkout [@Sachila Ranawaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74930967/8822610) instead

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 

The ! will indicate to the Typescript compiler that you are sure that `files` can never be null or undefined which should be correct in all modern browser as long as the input type is "file". If `files[0]` is not there it will set `undefined` which seems to be expected. You might want to add a little explanation when answering a question in the future to show that you have considered these cases so people will learn the reason behind an answer.